# What does "maximized" mean in propositional logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time now because I realized that I don't completely know the meanings of some terms. Would really appreciate if anyone can explain what the problem wants me to do.

```
Let x = 1033
a. Find its base 2 representation
b. Find a number y<=x such that:
    i. x^y is maximized
    ii. x∨y is maximized
    iii. x⊕y is maximized
```

I've already gotten a, so the base 2 is 10000001001.
What I don't quite understand is b. 
I know how to obtain x^y, x∨y, and x⊕y if both x and y are given, but since y isn't given, i don't know what to do next.
Is it asking me to look for a y? And what does maximized even mean?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Could you explain what the various symbols mean in this contest?

Comment: @Leo163
i. x^y is x AND y,
ii. x∨y is x OR y,
iii. x⊕y is x XOR y,
sorry bout that...kind of new to this

Comment: maximized means that your task is to find such $y$, that for no other number that could be $y$ the result of that operation is bigger.

Comment: @TStancek A problem for your answer lies in that numerals don't have size in propositional logic.  Numerals merely represent truth values.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood He obviously has a restriction in arithmetic terms for y, so it is not so impossible the maximization is also in arithmetic terms.

Comment: @TStancek My comment more goes to the effect that this isn't a question about propositional logic.